# Extracting raw data from a PowerPivot model using Python

Tags: python, excel, ssas, ado, powerpivot

What seemed like a trivial task turned into a real nightmare when I had to read in some data from a PowerPivot model using Python. I believe I've researched this very well over the last couple of days but now I hit a brick wall and would appreciate some help from the Python/SSAS/ADO community.

Basically, all I want to do is programmatically access raw data stored in PowerPivot models - my idea was to connect to the underlying PowerPivot (i.e. MS Analysis Services) engine via one of the methods listed below, list the tables contained in the model, then extract the raw data from each table using a simple DAX query (something like `EVALUATE (table_name)`). Easy peasy, right? Well, maybe not.

## 0. Some Background Information

As you can see, I've tried several different approaches. I'll try to document everything as carefully as possible so that those uninitiated in PowerPivot functionality will have a good idea of what I'd like to do.

First of all, some background on programmatic access to Analysis Services engine (it says 2005 SQL Server, but all of it ought to still be applicable): [SQL Server Data Mining Programmability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345148.aspx) and [Data providers used for Analysis Services connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn141152.aspx).

The sample Excel/PowerPivot file I'll be using in the example below can be found here: [Microsoft PowerPivot for Excel 2010 and PowerPivot in Excel 2013 Samples](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102).

Also, note that I'm using Excel 2010, so some of my code is version-specific. E.g. `wb.Connections["PowerPivot Data"].OLEDBConnection.ADOConnection` should be `wb.Model.DataModelConnection.ModelConnection.ADOConnection` if you're using Excel 2013.

The connection string I'll be using throughout this question is based on the information found here: [Connect to PowerPivot engine with C#](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0b9499f6-f80f-4dcc-8ab9-c52574b14a70/connect-to-powerpivot-engine-with-c). Additionally, some of the methods apparently require some sort of initialization of the PowerPivot model prior to data retrieval. See here: [Automating PowerPivot Refresh operation from VBA](https://gobansaor.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/automating-powerpivot-refresh-operation-from-vba/).

Finally, here's a couple of links showing that this should be achievable (note however, that these links mainly refer to C#, not Python):

- [Made connection to PowerPivot DataModel, how can I fill a dataset with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763513/made-connection-to-powerpivot-datamodel-how-can-i-fill-a-dataset-with-it)
- [Connecting to PowerPivot with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242557/connecting-to-powerpivot-with-c-sharp)
- [2013 C# connection to PowerPivot DataModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643366/2013-c-sharp-connection-to-powerpivot-datamodel)
- [Connecting Tableau and PowerPivot. It just works.](http://tableaulove.tumblr.com/post/76758976141/connecting-tableau-and-powerpivot-it-just-works) (showing that external apps can in fact read PowerPivot model data - note that the Tableau add-in installs `Interop.ADODB.dll` assembly, which I guess is what it uses to access the PowerPivot data)

## 1. Using ADOMD

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient")
import Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient as ADOMD
ConnString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=$Embedded$;Locale Identifier=1033;
             Location=H:\\PowerPivotTutorialSample.xlsx;SQLQueryMode=DataKeys"

Connection = ADOMD.AdomdConnection(ConnString)
Connection.Open()
```

Here, it appears the problem is that the PowerPivot model has not been initialized:

```
AdomdConnectionException: A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.
```

## 2. Using AMO

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")
import Microsoft.AnalysisServices as AMO
ConnString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=$Embedded$;Locale Identifier=1033;
             Location=H:\\PowerPivotTutorialSample.xlsx;SQLQueryMode=DataKeys"

Connection = AMO.Server()
Connection.Connect(ConnString)
```

Same story, "the server is not running":

```
ConnectionException: A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.
```

Note that AMO is technically not used for querying data, but I included it as one of the potential ways of connecting to the PowerPivot model.

## 3. Using ADO.NET

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Data")
import System.Data.OleDb as ADONET
ConnString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=$Embedded$;Locale Identifier=1033;
             Location=H:\\PowerPivotTutorialSample.xlsx;SQLQueryMode=DataKeys"

Connection = ADONET.OleDbConnection()
Connection.ConnectionString = ConnString
Connection.Open()
```

This is similar to [What's the simplest way to access mssql with python or ironpython?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/301746). Unfortunately, this also doesn't work:

```
OleDbException: OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: The following system error occurred:
The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
```

## 4. Using ADO via adodbapi module

```
import adodbapi
ConnString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=$Embedded$;Locale Identifier=1033;
             Location=H:\\PowerPivotTutorialSample.xlsx;SQLQueryMode=DataKeys"

Connection = adodbapi.connect(ConnString)
```

Similar to [Opposite Workings of OLEDB/ODBC between Python and MS Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951912/oppposite-workings-of-oledb-odbc-between-python-and-ms-access-vba). The error I get is:

```
OperationalError: (com_error(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB
Provider for SQL Server 2012 Analysis Services.', u'OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: The
following system error occurred:  The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested
type was found...
```

This is basically the same problem as with ADO.NET above.

## 5. Using ADO via Excel/win32com module

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Xlfile = "H:\\PowerPivotTutorialSample.xlsx"
XlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
Workbook = XlApp.Workbooks.Open(Xlfile)
Workbook.Connections["PowerPivot Data"].Refresh()
Connection = Workbook.Connections["PowerPivot Data"].OLEDBConnection.ADOConnection
Recordset = Dispatch('ADODB.Recordset')

Query = "EVALUATE(dbo_DimDate)" #sample DAX query
Recordset.Open(Query, Connection)
```

The idea for this approach came from this blog post that uses VBA: [Export a table or DAX query from Power Pivot to CSV using VBA](https://www.powerpivotblog.nl/export-a-table-or-dax-query-from-power-pivot-to-csv-using-vba/). Note that this approach uses an explicit Refresh command that initializes the model (i.e. "server"). Here's the error message:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'ADODB.Recordset', u'Arguments are of
the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.',
u'C:\\Windows\\HELP\\ADO270.CHM', 1240641, -2146825287), None)
```

It appears, however, that the ADO connection has been established:

- `type(Connection)` returns `instance`
- `print(Connection)` returns `Provider=MSOLAP.5;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Microsoft_SQLServer_AnalysisServices;Data Source=$Embedded$;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;ConnectTo=11.0;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Subqueries=2;Optimize Response=3;Cell Error Mode=TextValue`

It seems the problem lies in the creation of the ADODB.Recordset object.

## 6. Using ADO via Excel/win32com, direct use of ADODB.Connection

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
ConnString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=$Embedded$;Locale Identifier=1033;
             Location=H:\\PowerPivotTutorialSample.xlsx;SQLQueryMode=DataKeys"

Connection = Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
Connection.Open(ConnString)
```

Similar to [Connection to Access from Python [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12761442) and [Query access using ADO in Win32 platform (Python recipe)](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/196462-query-access-using-ado-in-win32-platform/). Unfortunately, the error Python spits out is the same as in the two examples above:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
Server 2012 Analysis Services.', u'OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: The following system
error occurred:  The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
..', None, 0, -2147467259), None)
```

## 7. Using ADO via Excel/win32com, direct use of ADODB.Connection plus model refresh

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Xlfile = "H:\\PowerPivotTutorialSample.xlsx"
XlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
Workbook = XlApp.Workbooks.Open(Xlfile)
Workbook.Connections["PowerPivot Data"].Refresh()
ConnStringInternal = "Provider=MSOLAP.5;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=
                     Microsoft_SQLServer_AnalysisServices;Data Source=$Embedded$;MDX
                     Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;ConnectTo=11.0;MDX Missing Member
                     Mode=Error;Optimize Response=3;Cell Error Mode=TextValue"

Connection = Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
Connection.Open(ConnStringInternal)
```

I was hoping I could initialize an instance of Excel, then initialize the PowerPivot model, and then create a connection using the internal connection string Excel uses for embedded PowerPivot data (similar to [How do you copy the powerpivot data into the excel workbook as a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33580647/5803031) - note that the connection string is different from the one I've used elsewhere). Unfortunately, this doesn't work and my guess is that Python starts the ADODB.Connection process in a separate instance (as I get the same error message when I execute the last three rows without first initializing Excel, etc.):

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
Server 2012 Analysis Services.', u'Either the user, ****** (masked), does not have access
to the Microsoft_SQLServer_AnalysisServices database, or the database does not exist.',
None, 0, -2147467259), None)
```

Comment: May I ask why you need to access the data in the PP model directly? Power Pivot data must be loaded from some other source, whether it be a data source that exposes a more robust ODBC interface (or other programmatic connectivity) or flat files that you could consume natively in Pyhon.

Comment: I work in an industry where we offen get PowerPivot data from third parties. They're not our clients, so we can't request the original data in a more suitable format, etc.

Comment: Understood. DAX Studio is capable of running arbitrary DAX queries against an open workbook. You might be able to dig into its internals or contact the maintainer, Darren Gosbell, for some more informed assistance on this: https://daxstudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @greggyb! I've already looked at DAX Studio, but since there's no notion of rows and row indices in PowerPivot/Vertipaq db engine, I don't think there's a way of limiting the DAX query to just a subset of records (I've done a fair share of research on this and I think this actually deserves an entirely new question). Anyway, this way one could get around Excel's 1m row limit by e.g. using a VBA script that would output 1m chunks of data into standalone workbooks (similar to what's suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33580647).

Comment: I should note that splitting the table into smaller chunks is only needed when there's more than 1m records (for example, the dbo_FactSales table in the sample file mentioned above), but not when the number of rows is smaller than that (e.g., the dbo_DimProduct table). In that case, the solution suggested in that SO link is super straightforward. I will reach out to Darren though to see if there's anything I might've missed. Thanks again!

Comment: DAX Studio can output to flat files, e.g. CSV. No need to chunk into 1M rows. Depending on your machine, you may hit memory limits, as evaluating a table requires the entire thing be decompressed in memory (and Vertipaq compression is strong). In terms of subsetting rows, you can use TOPN(), so long as you can identify a suitable sort-key (need not be unique). See this recent thread for similar discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748748/rip-data-from-power-pivot-item-data

Comment: Perfect, I was just experimenting with DAX Studio (and getting the "The server sent an unrecognizable response." error), but I didn't know about the export to CSV functionality... This is just what I need, although I'd still prefer if the entire thing could be automated in Python. Not sure if I like using the TOPN() approach on sorted data though - I was thinking of generating random numbers (or maybe using a function of two to three random numbers to guarantee uniqueness) and then using RANKX() to get "row indices", which I could then somehow use to subset data...

Comment: Add a calculated column to the model: Rand=RANDBETWEEN(1, N). Then run N queries in DAX Studio: EVALUATE CALCULATETABLE( 'Table', [Rand] = x )

Comment: @greggyb, thanks but I'm not sure how this is going to work so that I can programmatically loop over all records exactly once (as I mustn't generate a new Rand column in every loop). I could manually create a calculated column in PowerPivot, save the modified file, then run N queries on it (either in DAX Studio or in Excel itself). But that's precisely what I'd like to do programmatically: use AMO to add a calculated column as suggested, then use ADO/MD to query all N subsets. I'd like to simplify the data extraction process as much as possible so our analysts (not computer-savvy) can use it.

Comment: That's why I'd do it on a natural key. For example, you could check that [Date] >= DATEVALUE( "2015-01-01" ) and [Date] <= DATEVALUE( "2015-12-31" ), and then increment your dates for the next year. You only need to split the file if the uncompressed model is larger than the working memory size on the host computer.

Comment: Thanks greggyb, yeah I think I'll probably have to do something like that. I'm wondering if I could potentially create a calculated column using AMO/XMLA from within Excel (i.e. using VBA) and basically inject it into my tables (keeping its values fixed when looping over queries). This would allow me to run queries on 1m+ non-numerical data sets where the whole notion of a natural key is missing...

Comment: It's been a while, but I just realized I never mentioned that conditioning on row numbers is indeed possible when working with PowerPivot models. I stumbled upon this when poring over SQL Server trace logs. Sample query: `SELECT * FROM [Model].[table] WHERE [Model].[table].[RowNumber]>=1000 AND [Model].[table].[RowNumber]<=2000`. RowNumber seems to be a hidden internal column. For this to work, the following must be appended to the connection string: `SQLQueryMode=DataKeys`. Here's an Excel "tool" for extracting PowerPivot data I wrote a while ago: http://github.com/akavalar/ExtractPowerPivot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lo and behold, I finally managed to crack the problem - turns out that accessing Power Pivot data using Python is indeed possible! Below's a short recap of what I did - you can find a more detailed description here: [Analysis Services (SSAS) on a shoestring](https://github.com/akavalar/SSAS-on-a-shoestring). Note: the code has been optimized neither for efficiency nor elegance.

- Install Microsoft Power BI Desktop (comes with free Analysis Services server, so no need for a costly SQL Server license - however, the same approach obviously also works if you have a proper license).
- Fire up the AS engine by first creating the msmdsrv.ini settings file, then restore the database from the ABF file (using AMO.NET), then extract data using ADOMD.NET.

Here's the Python code that illustrates the AS engine + AMO.NET parts:

```
import psutil, subprocess, random, os, zipfile, shutil, clr, sys, pandas

def initialSetup(pathPowerBI):
    sys.path.append(pathPowerBI)

    #required Analysis Services assemblies
    clr.AddReference("Microsoft.PowerBI.Amo.Core")
    clr.AddReference("Microsoft.PowerBI.Amo")     
    clr.AddReference("Microsoft.PowerBI.AdomdClient")

    global AMO, ADOMD
    import Microsoft.AnalysisServices as AMO
    import Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient as ADOMD

def restorePowerPivot(excelName, pathTarget, port, pathPowerBI):   
    #create random folder
    os.chdir(pathTarget)
    folder = os.getcwd()+str(random.randrange(10**6, 10**7))
    os.mkdir(folder)

    #extract PowerPivot model (abf backup)
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(excelName)
    for member in archive.namelist():
        if ".data" in member:
            filename = os.path.basename(member)
            abfname = os.path.join(folder, filename) + ".abf"
            source = archive.open(member)
            target = file(os.path.join(folder, abfname), 'wb')
            shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
            del target
    archive.close()

    #start the cmd.exe process to get its PID
    listPIDpre = [proc for proc in psutil.process_iter()]
    process = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe /k', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    listPIDpost = [proc for proc in psutil.process_iter()]
    pid = [proc for proc in listPIDpost if proc not in listPIDpre if "cmd.exe" in str(proc)][0]
    pid = str(pid).split("=")[1].split(",")[0]

    #msmdsrv.ini
    msmdsrvText = '''<ConfigurationSettings>
       <DataDir>{0}</DataDir>
       <TempDir>{0}</TempDir>
       <LogDir>{0}</LogDir>
       <BackupDir>{0}</BackupDir>
       <DeploymentMode>2</DeploymentMode>
       <RecoveryModel>1</RecoveryModel>
       <DisklessModeRequested>0</DisklessModeRequested>
       <CleanDataFolderOnStartup>1</CleanDataFolderOnStartup>
       <AutoSetDefaultInitialCatalog>1</AutoSetDefaultInitialCatalog>
       <Network>
          <Requests>
             <EnableBinaryXML>1</EnableBinaryXML>
             <EnableCompression>1</EnableCompression>
          </Requests>
          <Responses>
             <EnableBinaryXML>1</EnableBinaryXML>
             <EnableCompression>1</EnableCompression>
             <CompressionLevel>9</CompressionLevel>
          </Responses>
          <ListenOnlyOnLocalConnections>1</ListenOnlyOnLocalConnections>
       </Network>
       <Port>{1}</Port>
       <PrivateProcess>{2}</PrivateProcess>
       <InstanceVisible>0</InstanceVisible>
       <Language>1033</Language>
       <Debug>
          <CallStackInError>0</CallStackInError>
       </Debug>
       <Log>
          <Exception>
             <CrashReportsFolder>{0}</CrashReportsFolder>
          </Exception>
          <FlightRecorder>
             <Enabled>0</Enabled>
          </FlightRecorder>
       </Log>
       <AllowedBrowsingFolders>{0}</AllowedBrowsingFolders>
       <ResourceGovernance>
          <GovernIMBIScheduler>0</GovernIMBIScheduler>
       </ResourceGovernance>
       <Feature>
          <ManagedCodeEnabled>1</ManagedCodeEnabled>
       </Feature>
       <VertiPaq>
          <EnableDisklessTMImageSave>0</EnableDisklessTMImageSave>
          <EnableProcessingSimplifiedLocks>1</EnableProcessingSimplifiedLocks>
       </VertiPaq>
    </ConfigurationSettings>'''

    #save ini file to disk, fill it with required parameters
    msmdsrvini = open(folder+"\\msmdsrv.ini", "w")
    msmdsrvText = msmdsrvText.format(folder, port, pid) #{0},{1},{2}
    msmdsrvini.write(msmdsrvText)
    msmdsrvini.close()

    #run AS engine inside the cmd.exe process
    initString = "\"{0}\\msmdsrv.exe\" -c -s \"{1}\""
    initString = initString.format(pathPowerBI.replace("/","\\"),folder)
    process.stdin.write(initString + " \n")

    #connect to the AS instance from Python
    AMOServer = AMO.Server()
    AMOServer.Connect("localhost:{0}".format(port))

    #restore database from PowerPivot abf backup, disconnect
    AMORestoreInfo = AMO.RestoreInfo(os.path.join(folder, abfname))
    AMOServer.Restore(AMORestoreInfo)
    AMOServer.Disconnect()

    return process
```

And the data-extraction part:

```
def runQuery(query, port, flag):
    #ADOMD assembly
    ADOMDConn = ADOMD.AdomdConnection("Data Source=localhost:{0}".format(port))
    ADOMDConn.Open()
    ADOMDCommand = ADOMDConn.CreateCommand() 
    ADOMDCommand.CommandText = query

    #read data in via AdomdDataReader object
    DataReader = ADOMDCommand.ExecuteReader()

    #get metadata, number of columns
    SchemaTable = DataReader.GetSchemaTable()
    numCol = SchemaTable.Rows.Count #same as DataReader.FieldCount

    #get column names
    columnNames = []
    for i in range(numCol):
        columnNames.append(str(SchemaTable.Rows[i][0]))

    #fill with data
    data = []
    while DataReader.Read()==True:
        row = []
        for j in range(numCol):
            try:
                row.append(DataReader[j].ToString())
            except:
                row.append(DataReader[j])
        data.append(row)
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
    df.columns = columnNames 

    if flag==0:
        DataReader.Close()
        ADOMDConn.Close()

        return df     
    else:   
        #metadata table
        metadataColumnNames = []
        for j in range(SchemaTable.Columns.Count):
            metadataColumnNames.append(SchemaTable.Columns[j].ToString())
        metadata = []
        for i in range(numCol):
            row = []
            for j in range(SchemaTable.Columns.Count):
                try:
                    row.append(SchemaTable.Rows[i][j].ToString())
                except:
                    row.append(SchemaTable.Rows[i][j])
            metadata.append(row)
        metadf = pandas.DataFrame(metadata)
        metadf.columns = metadataColumnNames

        DataReader.Close()
        ADOMDConn.Close()

        return df, metadf
```

The raw data are then extracted via something like this:

```
pathPowerBI = "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Power BI Desktop/bin"
initialSetup(pathPowerBI)
session = restorePowerPivot("D:/Downloads/PowerPivotTutorialSample.xlsx", "D:/", 60000, pathPowerBI)
df, metadf = runQuery("EVALUATE dbo_DimProduct", 60000, 1)
endSession(session)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with getting data out of PowerPivot is that the tabular engine in PowerPivot runs in-process inside Excel and the **only** way to connect to that engine is to have your code running inside Excel too. (I suspect that it may use shared memory or some other transport, but it's definitely not listening on a TCP port or a named pipe or anything like that which would allow an external process to connect)

We do this in Dax Studio by running a C# VSTO Excel add-in in Excel. However that was only designed to work for testing analytic queries, not for doing bulk data extraction. We marshal the data across from the add-in to the UI using a string variable so the entire dataset must be less than 2Gb or the response gets truncated and you will see an "unrecognizable response" error (the data is serialized into an XMLA rowset which is quite verbose so may see it break when only extracting a few hundred Mb of data)

If you wanted to build a script to automate extracting all the raw data from a model I don't think you will be able to do it with Python as I don't believe you can get the python interpreter running in-process inside Excel. I would look at using a vba macro like this one http://www.powerpivotblog.nl/export-a-table-or-dax-query-from-power-pivot-to-csv-using-vba/

You should find that you can query the model for a list of tables with something like "SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_TABLES" - you could then loop over each table and extract with a variation of the code in the above link.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you input, Darren!

Comment: Darren, couldn't you automatically subset the data into chunks that you'd then pipe into Dax Studio to get around the 2Gb limit when dealing with massive PowerPivot models? Say if you pull out 1M rows at a time and then assemble everything back together in the end?

Comment: @akavalar - there probably is a way of chunking the data, but that would require a lower level implemenation of the XMLA protocol than we currently have. And this is not really a priority for us at the moment. If someone needs a detailed data dump it would be better to get that from the original source system than to extract it from a PowerPivot model.

Answer (score 1):

I got in touch with Tom Gleeson (aka Gobán Saor) who was kind enough to let me post his emails here. There are some interesting nuggets in them, so hopefully others will also find them useful.

**Email #1**

> When you say Python, you mean running Python.NET as a standalone exe?
> If that’s the case, you’re out of luck with Excel PP models (different
> story for Power BI desktop though). I’ve accessed PP models (2010+)
> successfully from both VBA, and from Python.NET (via AMO) using
> similar code to that in your SO question. The difference being (in
> both VBA & .NET version) is that my code is running in-process within
> Excel using Excel’s various add-in technologies. (Likely Tableau is
> also running as an add-in or has embedded Excel within itself enabling
> similar behaviour). DAX Studio (a useful C# code base to learn the
> how-tos of PP access) runs both as an Excel add-in and as a standalone
> EXE, but only as an add-in can it access Excel based PP models.

**Email #2**

> You might find the process of using Python.NET for this somewhat
> challenging. You would need to embed a Python engine using C#/VB.NET
> Excel add-in code. I’ve used Excel-DNA (a fantastic open source
> project) rather than MS’s highly cumbersome "official" method for
> developing such .NET addins in the past, but I mainly stick to VBA
> where at all possible.
>
> Using VBA you’ll not be able to access the
> .NET-only AMO (so no ability to create calculated columns on the fly),
> but by loading the resulting dataset into an ADO recordset you should
> be able to output to a worksheet OR to a corporate-database/MS Access
> OR to a flat-file/CSV etc.
>
> Unlike the 1M worksheet limit, for a
> flat-file or database output memory (RAM) will be the limiting factor,
> but, assuming you’re using 64bit Excel and have enough memory to hold
> the compacted model and the workspace for the largest of the model’s
> tables in un-compacted form (i.e. a row based rather than column based
> format that’ll result from a DAX Query), multiplied by 2ish (one
> instance within PP workspace the other within VBA’s ADO workspace) you
> should be okay.
>
> Having said that, I’ve never attempted extracting a
> very large dataset, and using models as a dataset exchange medium is
> not one of PP’s "use-cases"; so, very large tables might hit some
> other bug/constraint!